# Why is nleqslv function returning a NULL output?

Tags: r

I intend to solve a system of nonlinear equations using nleqslv package. This is the R script below.

```
library("nleqslv")

require(nleqslv)

x <- c(1.4,1.6,1.8,2)

NMfun1 <- function(g) {

  y <- numeric(3)

  y[1] <- -(4/g[1])-(4*log(g[2]))-sum(log(x))+sum((g[2]*x)^g[1]*log(g[2]*x))+2*sum(g[3]*(g[2]*x)^g[1]*log(g[2]*x)*exp(-(g[2]*x)^g[1])*(1-g[3]*exp(-(g[2]*x)^g[1]))^(-1))

  y[2] <- -(4*g[1]/g[2])+sum(g[2]*x*(g[2]*x)^(g[1]-1))+2*sum(g[1]*g[3]*x*(g[2]*x)^(g[1]-1)*exp(-(g[2]*x)^g[1])*(1-g[3]*exp(-(g[2]*x)^g[1]))^(-1))

  y[3] <- (4/(g[3]-1))-2*sum(exp(-(g[2]*x)^g[1])*(1-g[3]*exp(-(g[2]*x)^g[1]))^(-1))

  y

}

gstart <- matrix(runif(3*100,min=0,max=1), nrow=100, ncol=3)

ans <- nleqslv(gstart,NMfun1, method="Newton", global="dbldog")

ans$g
```

I believe I am not doing something right in my code because I keep getting NULL after running the code.
I need your help. Thank you

Comment: Please modify your title!

Comment: Please use the formatting settings indicated by SO https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, this will help other understand the question and help you solve the problem.

Comment: Well come to stackoverflow. You should pick a title to explain your question.

Comment: There is no `g` element in the result from `searchZeros`.  Hence, NULL. See [here](https://github.com/cran/nleqslv/blob/master/R/searchzeros.R), at the bottom.

Comment: @RichardScriven, post as answer ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker - Okay, changed my mind again :)

Comment: If the variable `x` is supposed to be a starting value for `NMfun1` why does it have length 4? Your function expects length 3. Why does it violate the constraints you specify in the call to `runif`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `g` element in the result from `searchZeros()`. Hence, `ans$g` returns `NULL`.

See [here](https://github.com/cran/nleqslv/blob/master/R/searchzeros.R), at the bottom. The list returned from `searchZeros()` does not contain an element named `g`. The following is the end of the function.

```
searchZeros <- function(x, fn, digits=4L, ... ) {

    ...  

    # return full precision solutions ordered with rounded ordering
    res <- list(x=xsol[zidxo,,drop=FALSE], xfnorm=fnorm[idxcvg][notdups][zidxo],
                fnorm=fnorm[idxcvg], idxcvg=idxcvg, idxxtol=idxxtol,
                idxnocvg=idxnocvg, idxfatal=idxfatal,
                xstart=solstart[zidxo,,drop=FALSE],cvgstart=xstartcvg)
    res
}
```

Comment: And the return value is also documented in the manual! I wish people would read manuals carefully!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with your problem. First, your code contains obvious flaws, i.e. g[2] can become negative resulting in taking the log of something negative which is undefined.

Inside `searchZeros` there is the line `if (!any(tcode == 1)) return(NULL)`. The object `tcode` gets filled with `output$termcd` from the function `nleqslv`. In the helpfile of `nleqslv` it says that a 1 for `output$termcd` means that convergence has been reached. In summary, if the function does not detect convergence it simply stops without any further information and returns `NULL`.

edit: Apologies to the creators of `nleqslv`, the case is documented in contrast to what I said before (although it cannot be found by searching for `NULL`).

Comment: thanks for the apologies! I do my utmost best to document stuff correctly. I'll see if I can be more explicit in the manual.

Comment: Good option.  Plus one.